# How to emphasize selected output in neural network

Tags: neural-network, pytorch

I'm training a data set with 17 features and 5 output using pytorch. But I'm most interested in two of them, let say output 2 and 3 out of 0-4. What's a good strategy to get as high accuracy as possible on 2 and 3, while the rest can have lower accuracy?

Comment: What kind of output layer is that? `nn.Linear`?

Comment: Please provide more info about your network and what each output represent. Do outputs 0-4 represent classification probability and each output is one class? Then you're looking for weighted loss ufnction

Comment: @Ivan yes, nn.Linear and currently using softmax activation function

Comment: It's a categorization problem so each represents a category, so the output is one 1 and others are 0s. I'll look into the weighted loss function, thanks! @Proko

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `nn.CrossEntropyLoss()`, you can pass in the weights to emphasize or de-emphasize certain classes. From the [PyTorch docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html):

> `torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight: Optional[torch.Tensor] = None, ...)`

The weights do not have to sum up to one, since PyTorch will handle that on its own when `reduction='mean'`, which is the default setting. The weights specify which classes to weigh more heavily when calculating the loss. In other words, the higher the weight, the higher the penalty for getting a prediction wrong for the particular set of classes with higher weights.

```py
# imports assumed

x = torch.randn(10, 5) # dummy data
target = torch.randint(0, 5, (10,)) # dummy targets

weights = torch.tensor([1., 1., 2., 2., 1.]) # emphasize classes 2 and 3
criterion_weighted = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight=weights)
loss_weighted = criterion_weighted(x, target)
```

Comment: I am using cross entropy loss, will definitely try this. Thanks a lot!!